# How to send a Null value in xml string

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, xml

The RefNo column in SQL Server table is of datatype bigint, and can accept Nulls.
I am saving multiple records via xml using c#. The code works good, but for a few records, the RefNo has to be null, and it is saving as 0 even when I comment the 'else' part in stringbuilder.

**SQL:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SaveActivity
@XMLData xml
AS
BEGIN
  IF @XMLData IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE #Temp(
            ActivityId uniqueidentifier,                
            RefNo int,
            Notes nvarchar(500)             
            );

    INSERT INTO tblActivityDetails(ActivityId,RefNo,Notes)        
      SELECT
        detail.query('ActivityId').value('.','uniqueidentifier') as ActivityId,
        detail.query('RefNo').value('.','int') as RefNo,
        detail.query('Notes').value('.','nvarchar(500)') as Notes           
      FROM
        @XMLData.nodes('/details/detail') AS xmlData(detail)
    END
END
```

**C#:**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.AppendLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>");
sb.AppendLine("<details>")

foreach(GridViewRow gr in gvActivity.Rows)
{
    HiddenField hdRefNo = (HiddenField)gr.FindControl("hdRefNo");
    HiddenField hdNotes = (HiddenField)gr.FindControl("hdNotes");

    string sRefNo = hdRefNo.value.ToString()=="0" ? null : 
                    hdRefNo.value.ToString();
    sb.AppendLine("<detail>");
        sb.AppendLine("<ActivityId>"+ gActivityId.ToString() + "</ActivityId>");

         if(sRefNo!="0")
           sb.AppendLine("<RefNo>"+ sRefNo + "</RefNo>");
         else
           sb.AppendLine("<RefNo></RefNo>");
        sb.AppendLine("<Notes>"+ hdNotes.value.ToString() + "</Notes>");
        sb.AppendLine("</detail>");
}
sb.AppendLine("</details>")
```

Comment: Don't know if that will work, but what if you will not add `<RefNo>` element? Also consider to use something like linq to xml to build xml document

Comment: It still saves 0. I tested by commenting the else condition.

Comment: BTW: put `1<2` to hdNotes.value and see what happens..

Comment: here `string sRefNo = hdRefNo.value.ToString()=="0" ? null :  hdRefNo.value.ToString();` you already check on "0" so after you don't need repeat it. your `sRefNo` can't be equal "0". So or del condition `sRefNo!="0"` or change it on `sRefNo!=null`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `query()` when fetching values. Use `values()` directly and you will get `NULL` if the RefNo node is missing.

```
detail.value('(RefNo/text())[1]','int') as RefNo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `""` instead of `null` in

```
string sRefNo = hdRefNo.value.ToString()=="0" ? null : 
                    hdRefNo.value.ToString();
```

like

```
string sRefNo = hdRefNo.value.ToString()=="0" ? "": 
                    hdRefNo.value.ToString();
```

and remove if else part and just keep the statement

```
sb.AppendLine("<RefNo>"+ sRefNo + "</RefNo>");
```

Comment: Saving 0....Is there something that can be changed in sql, to insert Null if it is a 0

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
string sRefNo = hdRefNo.value.ToString()=="0" ? null : 
                hdRefNo.value.ToString();
```

your checking string and if it equals "0" that assign `null`, so when you after try checking

```
if(sRefNo!="0") // this condition always true
    sb.AppendLine("<RefNo>"+ sRefNo + "</RefNo>");
else
    sb.AppendLine("<RefNo></RefNo>");
```

Possibly if you change condition to `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sRefNo)` it will be work as expected

---

When you try get `int` field and in xml it don't set, then here

```
....
detail.query('RefNo').value('.','int') as RefNo,
....
```

will be return default value, i.e. `0` 
for solving you can try use `number()` function like this

```
....
detail.query('RefNo').value('number(.)','int') as RefNo,
....
```